# How do I access a specific element in the inner HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to use JS or jQuery to access an html value called "data-button". I can access the whole HTML div and pull out class name as well as the text content from the button, but I cant get the data-button value.

In the code below I have a captureRecipeButtons() function that can get the "recipe-1-container" div.

```
function captureRecipeButtons(){
  let theWholeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("recipe-1-container")[0];
  let buttonValue = ?; 
}

<div class="recipe-1-container">
   <button class="listed-recipe-link" data-button="1">Element</button>
</div>
```

In my captureRecipeButtons() function I want buttonValue to equal "1" in my above code. Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Comment: have you seen https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes ?

Comment: could you post the html please

Comment: As far as I know using .innerhtml  only returns a string, you could use a itenerator to go through it all but a MUCH easer method would to be to use .ChildNodes[0] to get the element that you want to edit or get or change and then use .innerHTML on the child node

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the full power of [CSS selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) with [`querySelector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector):

```
function captureRecipeButtons(){
    let button = document.querySelector(".recipe-1-container [data-button]");
}
```

`querySelector` returns the first matching element (or `null` if none do).

If you wanted the *value* of `data-selector` on that element, then `getAttribute` or `dataset`:

```
function captureRecipeButtons(){
    let buttonValue = document.querySelector(".recipe-1-container [data-button]").getAttribute("data-button");
    // or
    let buttonValue = document.querySelector(".recipe-1-container [data-button]").dataset.button;
}
```

Live Copy:

```js
function captureRecipeButtons(){
    const button = document.querySelector(".recipe-1-container [data-button]");
    console.log(button.getAttribute("data-button"));
    // or
    console.log(button.dataset.button);
}
captureRecipeButtons();
```

```html
<div class="recipe-1-container">
   <button class="listed-recipe-link" data-button="1">Element</button>
</div>
```

But note that [`dataset`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset) does some transformations.

---

But there are lots of different ways to do this. More to explore in [the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document_Object_Model).

Answer (score 1):

So you could just get the button element by class or tag name as I have done. then data-button is legit just an attribute so just use getAttribute('data-button');

The way I've written below will just get the first button that is a direct child of theWholeDiv element.

```js
function captureRecipeButtons(){
  let theWholeDiv = document.getElementsByClassName("recipe-1-container")[0];
  let buttonValue = theWholeDiv.getElementsByTagName('button')[0].getAttribute('data-button'); 
  console.log(buttonValue);
}

captureRecipeButtons();
```

```html
<div class="recipe-1-container">
   <button class="listed-recipe-link" data-button="1">Element</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [Mozilla Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes#JavaScript_access),

You can access the Data attributes via the `dataset` object.

```
function captureRecipeButtons(){
  let theButton = document.querySelector("recipe-1-container > button");
  let buttonValue = theButton.dataset.button; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way using the DOM, including some short-cuts to avoid excessive horizontal scrolling. The code precisely targets the first DIV element and its first BUTTON element, using the getAttribute() method to return the value of the indicated property.  What is nice about JavaScript is the fabulous amount of chaining that one can do between parent and child elements.

```js
function captureRecipeButtons() {
  let d = document;
  d.g = d.getElementsByTagName;
  let buttonValue = d.g("div")[0].getElementsByTagName("button")[0].getAttribute("data-button");
  console.log(buttonValue);
};

captureRecipeButtons();
```

```html
<div class="recipe-1-container">
  <button class="listed-recipe-link" data-button="1">Element</button>
</div>
```

Alternatively, you could write code as follows:

```js
function captureRecipeButtons() {
  let d = document;
  d.g = d.getElementsByTagName;

  let button = d.g("div")[0].childNodes[1];
  button.g = button.getAttribute;

  let buttonValue = button.g("data-button");
  console.log(buttonValue);
}

captureRecipeButtons();
```

```html
<div class="recipe-1-container">
  <button class="listed-recipe-link" data-button="1">Element</button>
</div>
```

The DIV element's first child node as per the format of the code is not the BUTTON element but a text object. The childNode[1] holds the BUTTON element, so you can use its getAttribute() method to retrieve the value of the **data-button** attribute.